# VS Code: Pushing and pulling always ask for password

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm using git in VS Code. I have a project in Azure DevOps. 3 months ago when I copied repo and pushed my first commit Git asked for my credentials. I entered username and generated password. After that everything was working fine. Starting march every time I pull or push VS Code askes for password. How can I save my password?

Answer (score 23):

```
git config credential.helper store
```

Then git will remember your credential locally. That config is also local.

Comment: this solution perfectly solve my problem.

Comment: omg this seems to be working so far.. thank you so much this was driving me INSANE.

Comment: But where within VSCode does one run this?

Comment: within terminal tab of VSCode.

Answer (score 2):

Check first what URL you are using:

```sh
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote -v
```

If it is an HTTPS URL, check what credential helper you are using

```
git config credential.helper
xxx
```

(For instance, `manager` or `manager-core`)

Then check what credential is attached to `dev.azure.com`, the server part of your remote URL:

```
printf "host=dev.azure.com\nprotocol=https" | git credential-xxx get
```

Replace `xxx` with the name of the credential helper for the previous step.

This work even in a Windows CMD, provided your %PATH% has `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` and `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core`

If your credential is not stored, you can register it again with `git credential-xxx store`:

```
printf "username=<you>\npassword=<token>\nhost=dev.azure.com\nprotocol=https" | git credential-xxx store
```

Replace `<you>` with your DevOps username, and `<token>` with an [Azure PAT (Personal Access token)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows).

Comment: So, in VS Code's terminal I tried `git remote-v` and it's indeed HTTPS Url. On second step `git config credential.helper` I got nothing as an answer in terminal

Comment: @IBlackVikingl You can execute it in a CMD/shell as well. In VSCode, make sure you are in the right folder.

Comment: @IBlackVikingl If you are on Windows, with the latest Git installed (Git 2.35.1.2), set the credential helper: `git config --global credential.helper manager-core`

Comment: I set it up. Now facing another error. `printf "host=dev.azure.com\nprotocol=https" | git credential-xxx get` command returns " printf : The term 'printf' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"

Comment: @IBlackVikingl Yes, see the PATH I mention in my answer.